# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from opening abc.exe in editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just started with Visual Studio Code.
One thing I find really strange is, if my code compiles to an *.exe, and I select it in the explorer, VS Code tries to "open" it, as if it was a text file, and then complains it's a binary file.

Ideally, it should do nothing when I select it, and I should have to easy way of running it if I want, like "double-click" or some option in context menu. I don't want to hide the .exe, I just want VSCode to know it cannot edit it, so it shouldn't try.

[EDIT] In case someone wonders why I'd single-left-click on something where that click "makes no sense", it's because I've spent the last 15 years using an IDE where that does *nothing* except select the file in the explorer, and so I got into the habit of click on things while I'm "thinking about it", for example when I'm talking about this file to someone else. That's a hard habit to get rid of, in particular since I'm still using that IDE in my "day job".

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to hide the `.exe`?

Comment: @ifconfig Well, for a start, if it's *not there* then I know that the last compilation failed. Secondly, I'm hoping there is some way to *execute* it from the explorer, which requires me being able to see it. Still waiting for an answer to that part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. There aren't any settings to control this and extensions can't block an editor from opening.

An extension COULD automatically close any tabs that were opened for a .exe file. So if you clicked on it and a tab opened, the extension could close it. I don't know if such an extension exists.

Otherwise you can create a feature request on github: https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new